# jQuery filter(this.hash) when not an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#block1">1<a/> </li>
    <li><a href="#block2">2<a/> </li>
     <li>3</li>
<ul>
<div id="block1">
     Block1
</div>
<div id="block2">
     Block2
</div>

 $('ul li:has(a)').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
            $('*[id^="block"]').hide();
          .filter(this.hash).show(); //WRONG//
            e.preventDefault();
      });
```

**[ONLINE SAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2TaT/)**

I know this would be easy to make the jQuery to just `click` on `a` tag and `.filter(this.hash).show();` ,

```
 $('ul li a').on('click', function(){
  $('*[id^="block"]').hide().filter(this.hash).show(); 
}
```

but I want to know & learn if there is another method to make this works. Thanks!

Comment: You have invalid syntax. What are you trying to access the `filter` method on?

Comment: $('ul li a').on('click', function(){  $('*[id^="tab"]').hide().filter(this.hash).show(); 
} this works. but the selector changed to `$('ul li:has(a)')` can can I pass `a href` value to `.filter(this.hash)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is incorrect, which causes a lot of problems:

- You are using `<a/>` instead of `</a>`.
- You are using `<ul>` instead of `</ul>`.

You are using `$('*[id^="tab"]').hide();` to try to hide the elements, but the identities are `block1` are `block2`, not `tab1` and `tab2`.

You are using `closest("a")` to try to find the link, but the link is inside the list item, not surrounding it.

Corrected HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="#block1">1</a> </li>
  <li><a href="#block2">2</a> </li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<div id="block1">
  Block1
</div>
<div id="block2">
  Block2
</div>
```

Corrected Javascript:

```
$('*[id^="block"]').hide();
$('*[id^="block"]:first').show();

$('ul li:has(a)').on('click', function (e) {
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  $('*[id^="block"]').hide();
  $($(this).find("a").attr('href')).show();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y2TaT/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot! copied incorrectly and rush!! thanks for `$($(this).find("a").attr('href')).show();`